# Parse empty tag with ElementTree

Tags: python, xml-parsing, elementtree

Trying to parse XML using ElementTree. I cannot figure out how to treat empty tags like `<tag/>`. If the tag is not present at all, `.find()` returns `None` and everything is fine. However with `<tag\>`, `.find()` returns something and the consequent attempt to call `text` fails with error:

```
TypeError: must be str, not NoneType
```

Failing example below. It will fail to parse the line `<tl><mpa/></tl>`

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

def getStuff(xml_message):
    message_tree = ElementTree.fromstring(xml_message)
    ns = {'a': 'http://www.example.org/a',
          'b': 'http://www.example.org/b'}          
    tls = message_tree.findall('.//b:tl', namespaces = ns)

    result, i = (0,)*2

    for tl in tls:
        i += 1     
        print("Item: " + str(i))
        mpa = tl.find("b:mpa", namespaces = ns)
        if mpa is None:
            result = result + 0
            print(" |--> Is None, assigned 0.")
        else:
            print(" |--> Is Something")
            # This is where things go terribly wrong
            print(" |--> Tag Value: " + mpa.text)
            result = result  + int(mpa.text)    
    return result

instr = """<?xml version="1.0" standalone='no'?>
<ncr xmlns="http://www.example.org/a">
  <x xmlns="http://www.example.org/b">
      <tl><ec code="N">e1</ec></tl>
      <tl><mpa>0010</mpa></tl>
      <tl><mpa/></tl>
  </x>
</ncr>
"""
getStuff(instr)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an empty tag `<mpa/>`, your `mpa` variable is a valid node so it is not `None`, but `mpa.text` is `None` because there's no text inside. Your attempt to concatenate a string `" |--> Tag Value: "` to `None` therefore fails since concatenation only works on two strings. Instead, you can use the formatting operator to format `None` as `'None'`, and add a condition to the following line to avoid converting `mpa.text` to an integer if it is `None`:

```
print(" |--> Tag Value: %s" % mpa.text)
if mpa.text is not None:
    result = result  + int(mpa.text)
```

With the above change the output becomes:

```
Item: 1
 |--> Is None, assigned 0.
Item: 2
 |--> Is Something
 |--> Tag Value: 0010
Item: 3
 |--> Is Something
 |--> Tag Value: None
```